# Non-existent directory specified in --libpath=

Tags: java, deducer

I have installed the JGR package but when I try to invoke it, the error says

`__Non-existent directory specified in --libpath=__. Maybe because of a white space in the path variable, __\Users\Scholars Psy\Documents\R\win-library\3.0__ which cannot be read?`

I am running a **64-bit Windows 7 OS**. I have installed both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Java.
I tried installing JGR using the .exe file from JGR website, which is also not working.

My ultimate need is to use Deducer, which seems to be working well from inside JGR only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space in the `Scholars Psy` folder name.

Specify directory with your command line argument.

example:

```
set R_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-30~1.1
set R_LIBS=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library
set R_LIBS_USER=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library
jgr-1_62-x64.exe --rhome=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-30~1.1 --libpath=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-30~1.1\library
```